# WebView Cookies

Tags: android

Как я могу реализовать, чтобы сохранялся Cookies сайта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Было уже много раз. Вот например на [SO: WebView and Cookies on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566485/).

Если в двух словах, то проблема в том, что при каждой загрузке браузер запускает новую сессию. Если же вы хотите, чтобы куки сохранялись и после закрытия приложения, то куки надо сохранять с помощью CookieSyncManager и CookieManager. Обо всём этом есть на SO по ссылке выше.